# Magento2: How to show product id in checkout order summay

Tags: magento2, product, checkout, attributes

I tried to include the productId in the checkout summary section but I can't figure how to do that.

if i override the `magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/item/details.html` and i add this line:

```
<strong class="product-item-id" data-bind="text: $parent.item_id"></strong>
```

I receive a strange number, but for sure is not the product id.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: have you tried $parent.product_id ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a breakpoint in developer tools and inspect the contents of any object.

Also theres [knockoutjs context debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/knockoutjs-context-debugg/oddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof?hl=en)  for chrome that will help you find the right context and variables you have at hand on specific DOM node in knockoutjs context.

by using this its really easy to get the result of whats your collection contains:

```
[  
{  
  "item_id":17,
  "price":19,
  "base_price":19,
  "qty":1,
  "row_total":19,
  "base_row_total":19,
  "row_total_with_discount":0,
  "tax_amount":0,
  "base_tax_amount":0,
  "tax_percent":0,
  "discount_amount":0,
  "base_discount_amount":0,
  "discount_percent":0,
  "price_incl_tax":19,
  "base_price_incl_tax":19,
  "row_total_incl_tax":19,
  "base_row_total_incl_tax":19,
  "options":"[]",
  "weee_tax_applied_amount":null,
  "weee_tax_applied":null,
  "name":"Sprite Foam Roller"
}
]
```

product real ID or SKU is sadly not part of this collection and to get it from there you would need to extend the output to cover that